# Exchanging $\partial$ for $d$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, physics

I have the following equation :

> $$\frac{aT^3}{P^2} = \frac{-1}{V}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial P} \right)_T$$  Where $a$ is a constant, $T$ and $P$ are the temperature and pressure, with $T$ being held constant.
> I need to find an expression for the volume $V$.

My question is can I proceed as in a separable ODE ? I mean writing :

$$\frac{-1}{V}dV = \frac{aT^3}{P^2}dP$$ and integrate to find $V$ ?

Comment: How do you obtain the LHS of your new ODE?

Comment: Probably not, notice that you are differentiating relative to pressure, thus $\partial P = dP = 1.$ Also, $\partial$ and $d$ are _just notations of convenience._ You can say $df$ refers to differentiating relative to $P$ and use it as usual (except that this is an ODE relative to $P$).

Comment: @JacobA there was a typo , I have fixed it now

Comment: Looks better. My only comment: If you solve the separable ODE and find that it satisfies the initial "PDE" then under physicist rigor, all is well. But I'm curious to hear more of the mathematician's perspective here as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without converting it to an ODE, we *can* say the following

$$\frac{aT^3}{P^2} = - \frac{1}{V}\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial P}\right)_T = - \left(\frac{\partial \log V}{\partial P}\right)_T $$

then integrate both sides with respect to $P$, but treating $T$ as an independent variable instead of another constant like $a$

$$\frac{aT^3}{P} = \log V  +f(T) \implies V = f(T)\exp\left(\frac{aT^3}{P}\right)$$

where the constant of integration is a function of $T$